# How can I view the usernames of those SSHing into my network?

Tags: ssh, users, user-accounts

I can see the IP address of the connecting computer. I am just curious as to whether I can get the username of the computer that is connecting into the network?

Comment: Do you mean the username the ssh'd user is using on your computer?  The name of the computer they're using? Or the username they're logged in as on the remote computer?

Comment: @Kevin I mean the username they're logged in as on the remote computer.

Comment: Then no, you can't find that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean you want to get the hostname?

If so, for the public IP, use: `nslookup`, `host`, `dig`, ...

```
$ nslookup 64.34.119.12
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
12.119.34.64.in-addr.arpa   name = stackoverflow.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
```

For the private IP, use: `nbtscan`, `nmblookup`, ...

```
$ nbtscan 192.168.15.32
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.15.32

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.15.32    VC-307           <server>  <unknown>        f4-6d-04-cd-0c-8e
```

Comment: Hm, thanks, this is helpful but I would really like the username on the remote computer?

Comment: You can't. What is your final goal?

Answer (score 1):

As stated earlier, you can get the systems involved, but not the specific usernames involved just by a network scan.  If you collected information from all the systems' syslogs (via a central logger) you could get the information of the usernames on the destination machines but NOT the username on the source machine.

Answer (score 0):

Like it's been stated before; unless the connecting systems are under your jurisdiction, you can't.